# How to get API gateway url in AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a scenario where I am using an API URL to invoke lambda function. After invoking the lambda function, I want that particular URL in the lambda function.

> https://******.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/first
>
> https://******.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/second

From this URL, I want the resource named first or second in lambda. Here the test is the stage name where I deplou\y my API. I have multiple resources created from that I want to change the behavior of lambda. How could I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can reconstruct the full url from values in the Lambda function's `events` variable.

```
events['headers']['Host'] = '******.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
events['requestContext']['stage'] = 'test'
events['path'] = '/first'
```

So altogether, you can get `https://******.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/first` from adding them together:

```
'https://' + events['headers']['Host'] + '/' + events['requestContext']['stage'] + events['path']
```

See the [Lambda Proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) part of the AWS documentation for details on other info you get can out of the events variable.