# How to access host in lambda behind both API gateway and cloudfront?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a lambda function being executed by an API gateway. I have cloudfront pointing traffic to the API gateway endpoint.

How do I access the host/domain the client is on in my lambda function?

Can I move the Host header to X-Forwarded-Host?

e.g.

`abc.com` (cloudfront) -> API gateway -> lambda (Host: abc.com)

Comment: What does "the client host in my lambda function" mean? confused.

Comment: Totally mistyped that. I mean the host domain the client is on.

Comment: is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575952/how-to-get-api-gateway-url-in-aws-lambda-function what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

In order to propagate `Host` header through Cloudfront and API Gateway, follow these steps:

#### Configure Cloudfront to forward `Host` header

[Step-by-step guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-cloudfront-to-forward-headers/)

Key points:

> Choose the Behaviors tab, and then choose the path that you want to forward the Host header to.

> Choose Edit.

> Under Cache key and origin requests, confirm that Legacy cache settings is selected. If it's not selected, then follow the steps in the preceding section to create a cache policy. If Legacy cache settings is selected, then complete the following:
> For Headers, select Include the following headers.
> From the Add header dropdown list, select Host.

#### Configure API Gateway request to relay `Host` header

Detailed docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-settings-method-request.html#setup-method-request-parameters)

Key point:

Edit your API Gateway resource(s) and for each method you need the `Host` header edit the Method Request by adding `Host` header in the *HTTP Request Headers* list.

---

You can also move the `Host` header to `X-Forwarded-Host` using a Cloudfront function but you would still need to follow the steps above to propagate `X-Forwarded-Host` header. You can try this out starting with [this sample function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-add-true-client-ip-header.html).